# How to follow a account in twitter using twitter4j Stream

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I'm working in a project in Java and I need to follow some twitter account to collect data about the traffic.
I started using the Twitter API but suddenly i found the limit too low so I changed to the stream API. Here there is no limit but I only know how to search something into the currect stream, not to get only the streams from the accounts I want.
Is that posiible with the twitter4J api?

My code is the following one:

```
 TwitterStream twitterStream = new TwitterStreamFactory(cb.build()).getInstance();

    StatusListener listener = new StatusListener() {

        @Override
        public void onException(Exception arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onDeletionNotice(StatusDeletionNotice arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onScrubGeo(long arg0, long arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onStatus(Status status) {

           //I process the tweet.

        }

        @Override
        public void onTrackLimitationNotice(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onStallWarning(StallWarning arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    };
    FilterQuery fq = new FilterQuery();


    String keywords[] = {"a","e","i","o","u"};

    fq.track(keywords);


    twitterStream.addListener(listener);
    twitterStream.filter(fq);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify users you want to follow using the `FilterQuery` object, e.g.:

```
long[] userIds = { ...omitted... };
fq.follow(userIds);

twitterStream.filter(fq);
```

Be aware that when filtering Tweets only need to match *one of the conditions*, i.e. the `track` or `follow`, so you may need to do some manual filtering if you intend to use both.

For more information check out Twitter's documentation for the [`follow` parameter](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis/parameters#follow) and [filter stream](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/statuses/filter).

Comment: Finally an answer. I was really wondering why using both wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

```
twitter.createFriendship("screenName");
```

Comment: You have posted only code. It would be better if you added some explanation or comment. Please [edit] your answer and add something. Thank you!